# What exactly needs to be PROTECTed when writing C functions for use in R

Tags: c, r, garbage-collection

I thought this was pretty straightforward, basically, any `SEXP` type objects I create in C code must be protected, but it starts getting a little murkier (to me) when using linked lists and `CAR` / `CDR`, etc.  I started off with this comment in **[Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Garbage-Collection)**:

> Protecting an R object automatically protects all the R objects pointed to in the corresponding SEXPREC, for example all elements of a protected list are automatically protected.

And this from **[R Internals](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#The-_0027data_0027)**:

> A SEXPREC is a C structure containing the 32-bit header as described above, three pointers (to the attributes, previous and next node) and the node data ...
>
> LISTSXP: Pointers to the CAR, CDR (usually a LISTSXP or NULL) and TAG (a SYMSXP or NULL).

So I interpret this to mean that, if I do something like:

```
SEXP s, t, u;
PROTECT(s = allocList(2));
SETCAR(s, ScalarLogical(1));
SETCADR(s, ScalarLogical(0));

t = CAR(s);
u = CADR(s);
```

Then `t` and `u` are protected by virtue of being pointers to objects that are within the protected list `s` (corollary question: is there a way to get the PROTECTED status of an object?  Couldn't see anything in Rinternals.h that fit the bill).  Yet I see stuff like (from `src/main/unique.c`):

```
// Starting on line 1274 (R 3.0.2), note `args` protected by virtue of being
// a function argument

SEXP attribute_hidden do_matchcall(SEXP call, SEXP op, SEXP args, SEXP env)
{
  // ommitting a bunch of lines, and then, on line 1347:
  
  PROTECT(b = CAR(args));

  // ...
}
```

This suggests all the objects within `args` are not protected, but that seems very odd since then any of the `args` objects could have gotten GCed at any point.  Since `CAR` just returns a pointer to a presumably already protected object, why do we need to protect it here?

Comment: I'd post this on r-devel rather than here...

Comment: To anyone contemplating this bounty, FYI, this one is going to @Leushenko in 23 hours unless you come up with something truly extraordinary.

Comment: Are you aware that you get this (and more) for free when you use Rcpp?  You never need `PROTECT` or `UNPROTECT`.  You are not forced to use other C++ features if you do not like them -- but this alone would make me switch. YMMV.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, I do realize, but I've been wanting to understand the nitty gritty of the actual R sources, and my question stemmed from this.  I was also looking to absolutely minimize overhead for a very fast operation and from what I could tell doing it in C with `.Call` is still the fastest for that very specific task (understanding that the time required to understand all the `.Call` intricacies likely nullifies any time savings from an operation that is 1.5us faster).

Comment: Sure, but you realize that that is a draw, correct?  Both C and C++ use the same `.Call()` interface.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, from what I recall in my early testing the same very simple operation (adding 1 + 1 or some such) was about 1.5 to 2 microseconds faster using raw `.Call` as opposed to wrapping it in `Rcpp`.  This was a while ago though.

Comment: Obviously such small timing differences are almost always completely meaningless.

Comment: Right.  I can write `cppFunction("double adder(const double a, const double b) { return a+b; }")` -- and then replace `double` by `NumericVector` to be vectorised.  And I'm not sure you'd _really_ end up with much faster code if you hand-tuned, but it would take you a lot longer to write it...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, agree completely, see parenthetical at end of my first response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about it this way: `PROTECT` doesn't actually do something to the object. Rather, it adds a temporary GC root so that the object is considered alive by the collector. Any objects it contains are also alive, not because of some protection applied from C, but because they are pointed-to by another object that is itself *already considered* alive - the same as any other normal live object. So setting the car of a protected list not only keeps that object alive, it also *potentially* releases whatever was previously in the car for GC, removing it from that particular live tree (protecting the list didn't recursively affect the elements).

So in general you aren't going to have an easy way of telling whether an object is "protected" or not in this wider sense, because it's actually just following the same rules as GC does elsewhere and there's nothing special about the object. You could potentially trace through the entire `PROTECT` list and see if you find it, but that would be... inefficient, to say the least (there's also nothing to say that the ownership tree leading to the object in question from the one on the `PROTECT` list is the one that will keep it alive for the longest).

The line in `do_matchcall` is actually there for a completely unrelated reason: protecting `CAR(args)` only happens in one branch of a conditional - in the other branch, it's a newly-created object that gets protected. Redundantly protecting the value from this branch as well means that there's guaranteed to be the same number of objects on the `PROTECT` stack regardless of which branch was taken, which simplifies the corresponding `UNPROTECT` at the end of the function to an operation on a constant number of slots (no need to replicate the check down there to vary it).

Comment: +1 for explaining the redundant PROTECT to keep PROTECT stack balance.  I would have never figured it out.  Under these rules presumably appending to a protected linked list will protect the objects pointed to by the new tail?

Comment: Also, why do SEXPRECs have a `mark` value under `sxpinfo_struct` as described in **[R internals](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#Rest-of-header)** if they are not "explicitly protected"?  I agree that the PROTECT code doesn't seem to modify the SEXP.

Comment: 1) yeah 2) a mark bit is usually used by a GC during the scan for live objects - all objects are marked 0, then during the scan those that are found are marked 1; any that are found already with a 1 don't need to be scanned again (in case of multiple owners or data cycles). Objects left with a 0 at the end of the scan are unreachable.

Comment: Great, thanks, this is super helpful and would have taken forever to figure out on my own given the sparse documentation and my general lack of knowledge of GC theory.